# Cisco Packer Tracer port labels all jumbled and covering each other

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer

Has anyone found a solution to make this look cleaner and more readable. I spend hours moving around the devices trying to figure out which interface is connected to which router and make so many errors. Is there a way to avoid this? I've lowered the font size to minimum, disabled the device name and model but still i'm not able to see these.

[image: Port Labels Jumbled up]

Comment: You just need to zoom out and move those devices apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Options > Preferences: Check the "Show port labels when mouse over". Then all port labels disappear and when mouse is over a link, the label appears.
2. I recommend don't use the labels and just use the Note to add everything such as link labels or IP addresses. You can add notes by push "N" button on keyboard.